# XCode fails to validate due to invalid version in info plist

Tags: ios, xcode, version, archive

This is driving me crazy.  I have finished a new version of an app that is on the app store.  The current version that is for sale is 1.68.  I want my new version to be 1.8.  I have the new version in all the right places in my app (I've checked this dozens of times).  But after I create an archive, it fails to validate because the version in my info.plist CFBundleShortVersionString [1.8] is not higher than the previously approved version [1.68].  I wasn't a Math Major, so correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure that 1.8 is in fact larger than 1.68.  I have created a record on iTunes Connect for the new 1.8 Version, it's sitting there waiting for me to upload the app.  I've tried lots of other version and build number combinations and ironically, if I set it to 1.69, it validates just fine.  I've also tried cleaning, deleting derived data, completely restarting everything, etc.  This is NOT the first time I've updated this app.  I've never had any trouble making a new version before.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: 8 is less than 68

Comment: I think I looks at those numbers separately. I mean not version 1,8 , but version 1 subversion 8 or something. So here 68 is bigger than 8, so you get the error. This is my guess. I suppose 1.80 won't give you the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation on [CFBundleShortVersionString](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-111349):

> The release version number is a string composed of three
>   period-separated integers. The first integer represents major revision
>   to the app, such as a revision that implements new features or major
>   changes. The second integer denotes a revision that implements less
>   prominent features. The third integer represents a maintenance release
>   revision.

To determine which version is higher, each of those integer slots is now compared with it's counterpart. In your case the first integers are equal ('1' and '1'), and for your second integer '68' is recognized (correctly) as being bigger than '8'.

Since Apple ignores leading zeroes, I think the closest you could get while keeping that "1.8" feeling would be going all the way to "1.80".

Comment: OK, this makes sense.  It explains why 1.68 would validate and 1.7 would not.  I was erroneously looking at the second number as a decimal and it clearly isn't.  It doesn't explain why 2.0 wouldn't validate when I tried it earlier today.  To avoid the future versions from getting uglier with bigger numbers, and since there were a couple of major changes to the app, I've decided to bump up to 2.0.0, and that validates just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use version code like this 
For minor builds it should be like 1.6.8
& for major release it should be like 1.8.0
& if you are uploading a build to be available on test flight say 1.8.0 
& it may have issues and you want to upload the 1.8.0 build again then you should update the build number